# How to save array of integer numbers in a column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 with the following properties:

```
Users (UserID, Username, Password)   where UserID is primary key
```

I want to save an array of integer numbers in the password attribute in the `Users` table.

```
--------------------
 0    1    2    3  
--------------------
1543 6543 7658 8765
--------------------
```

I plan to save this into the `password` column.

On the other hand I use pictures instead of texts for password and each picture has a code (4 digit) and a password include 4 picture that produce 16 digit. I want to save these 16 digits (array of Ints) into the `Password` column

please help me.

thanks

Comment: seriously, just don't...!! If it's a password, store it as a password (encrypted and salted of course)

Comment: of course it must be! You are saving into a column named 'Password'. you wouldn't be storing anything else in there would you?

Comment: yes it correct but my password is not a password eg. it is Passface

Comment: on the the other hand i use pictures insted texts for password and each picture has a code (4 digit) and a password include 4 picture that produce 16 dgit. i want to save this 16 digit (array of Ints) to Password Column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general arrays are saved in SQL tables as another table, one table row per array element.

But that does not look though like an array of ints, that looks more like 16 byte vector, probably an MD5 digest. Make a `VARBINARY(20)` column (this way you can switch to SHA1 without changing the column type) and store the byte array as a ... byte array. See [`SqlBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbytes.aspx) for how to manipulate `BINARY` and `VARBINARY` columns in the client.